# Jquery: Masonry, vertical and horizontal gap

Tags: jquery

I am currently working on my portfolio site.
However, while working on Mansonry, I found that there is a vertical and horizontal gap on the bottom of each image. I set margin, and padding to 0, however it does not go away. What interests me is that when I resize the window, the horizontal gap gose away, but the small part of image is overlapping the image placed next (gotta look at it closely).

http://jsfiddle.net/L2mzU/1/

```
 img {max-width: 100%;

}
#content {
    width:100%;
}


.container{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
```

I wonder whether it gots do with CSS..

I want no vertical and horizontal gaps, also no overlapping. how can i accomplish this?

your help will be much appreciated. !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the small gap below each image, simply add a vertical align of `top` (or bottom or a few others) to your images' css.

```
img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

By default the images are aligned `baseline` which leaves a small gap below the image (for text, letters like y and g go below the baseline, this room is for them).

Comment: Thank you so much! it definitely works great! I really appreciate your answer!!